# Sending to different Pages depending on Web.config Razor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I want to have a status page that will show a different layout of the equipment depending on who's using it which will be a variable defined in the web.config.  Should I be creating a separate controller per view?  Some of the background functions should be similar but some will probably be different in the future.  Or should I have the same cshtml file and hide html markup depending on who's using it or not?

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
@if(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsSuperUser"] == "true")
{
    <a href="@Url.Action("SuperUserIndex", "Status")">Status</a>
}
else {
    <a href="@Url.Action("UserIndex", "Status")">Status</a>
}
```

Or is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options, it all depends on your needs and preferences.

Your code will work, **however** you must also double check permission in your controller! For example, your url will be "/SuperUser/Status" and "/User/Status". Now, what's stopping non-super user to type in "/SuperUser/Status" to the address bar?

One important rule, **never trust the end users!** Assume that they will not do what you intend them to do.

Given all, my preference would be to include a variable in your Model to identify the user level (super vs non super), then use that to determine the layout in your views. Remember, you can also change the layout of the view based on variable/expression.

```
@Layout = Model.IsSuperUser ? "_SuperLayout.cshtml" : "_RegularLayout.cshtml";
```

Comment: Would this work if not only was the layout different but the information had to be sorted differently because there are different types depending on whether it's a superuser or not?

Comment: @roostersign By 'different types', do you mean they have different Model? If that's the case, you're going to have to handle that in the Controller.

Comment: Yes, the reason why the layout is different is because the models being passed up are different.

Comment: In that case, I would advise handling everything in Controller. In there, you can pick which Model you are generating and which View you want to display it on.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a view concern. I would pass the config data through a dependency in the controller and render partials:

```
@if (Model.IsSuperUser)
{
    @Html.Partial("_SuperUser")
}
else
{
    @Html.Partial("_User")
}
```

The controller can then do something like:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    vm.IsSuperUser = _config.GetSuperUser();
    return View(vm);
}
```